# Use memcached and not memcache in Joomla

Tags: joomla, memcached

My host has memcached and i want to configure it right. Last try i used memcache and my host update servers and missed to activate memcache and site went down. They reply that memcache is old and will soon not to be supported. So now i try to use memcache**d**

But i be so confused all guide´s/how to talk about memcache not memcached?

In configuration file they say change:

public $caching = '2';

public $cache_handler = 'memcache';

Should this not to be memcache**d**?

public $memcache_persist = '1';

public $memcache_compress = '0';

public $memcache_server_host = 'localhost';

public $memcache_server_port = '11211';

public $memcached_persist = '1';

public $memcached_compress = '0';

public $memcached_server_host = 'localhost';

public $memcached_server_port = '11211';

public $redis_persist = '1';

Should i change memcache or memcahe**d** to right port and server host?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcache and Memcached are indeed two different things (though they do use some similar underlying architecture at the server level).

It is true that Memcache (no d) is an older thing and is officially not supported on PHP 7, while Memcached (with the d) is still actively maintained and supported on current PHP versions.

So, if you are intending to use Memcached (with the d), first log into your Joomla backend and see if the option is even available in the global config (the available handler list is dynamic based on what your server has installed and enabled).  If you don't even see Memcached in that list, make sure you have all prerequisites set up (that should just be having PHP's ext/memcached installed and enabled).  Then, you can safely change the `$cache_handler` option to 'memcached'.